# question about "der Satz"

Tags: grammatical-case

source: https://youtu.be/gsfTkeF5tNU?t=50
pls pause at 0:50

> 1. In diesen Sätzen steht das Verb am Ende im Infinitiv.

shouldn't the word "der Satz" in the sentence below be correct?

> 2. In dieser Sätze steht das Verb am Ende im Infinitv

Why is there an *-en* at the end of the demonstrative article and *der Satz* in the first sentence? It does not make sense, does it? im not sure why the demonstrative article and der Satz has "en" at the end.

Vielen dank!

Answer (score 1):

**Prepositional objects with "in"**

"In" asks for dative case when referring to a position (within) and for accusative case when referring to a direction (into).
The prepositional object "in diesem Satz" is thus constructed with both article and noun in dative case.

---

> In diese**m** Satz steht das Verb im Infinitiv am Satzende.

**Declension of *der Satz*, (m.), sing.**

Der Satz [nom], des Satzes [gen], de**m** Satz [dat], den Satz [acc].
The article followes this structure.

> In dies**en** Sätz**en** steht das Verb im Infinitiv am Satzende.

**Declension of *die Sätze*, (m.), plur.**
Die Sätze [nom], der Sätze [gen], de**n** Sätz**en** [dat], die Sätze [acc]. Same here.

---

**The following -vs- this**

Note that both your examples do **not** feature a verb at the end of sentence, but in second position, as is the rule for main clauses in German.

The demonstrative pronoun is thus used wrongly here (as without further context, it refers to the very sentence it is used in)!

I guess you found these example sentences as titles to actual examples with verbs at the closure; in that case, better is

> Im folgenden Satz/ in den folgenden Sätzen...

Comment: i didnt know that nouns have to take the endings of a case as well. i mean i havent seen a plural noun like "Der Satz" with more than just an "e" at the end. I suppose that is why i got so tripped up about this video when i saw "in diesen Sätzen" I thought it would look like this "in diesen Sätze" But i think now i understand.  So what follows with plural dative also follows to the noun?

Comment: Here, the preposition 'in' dictates the use of dative, applied to the noun and, if present, its article. 'In diesem Satz' or plural: 'In diesen Sätzen' makes for one prepositional object, its core in dative case, but after that (which is after the noun as you put it), new sentence constituents appear.

Comment: If a demonstrative pronoun is used in conjunction with the noun it refers to, then both have to be in the same case. Following that, we see here the normal declination of the noun, and a demonstrative pronoun used instead of the definitive article. Here it's in the Dativ case as commanded by the proposition 'in'.

Comment: @Aaron Valenzuela: Plural nouns in general have an *n* ending in the dative, assuming they don't already have one. There are quite a few nouns which have *n* ending for the plural in all cases: *Woche*, *Frau* are some common ones. It's a typical plural ending for nouns ending in *e* and feminine nouns. There are a few nouns which have a *n* ending in the dative singular as well; most of them are masculine. So yeah, declining nouns is difficult in German.